# Unable to create POJO for a particular XML file (parsing xml)

Tags: java, android, xml, retrofit2

I'm using Retrofit 2 with SimpleXmlConverterFactory. What I'm trying to do is to parse the falues from here [XML link](http://view-source:http://www.cbr.ru/scripts/XML_daily.asp)

Just in case if the link would be stale some day, here is the short example of XML I'm trying to parse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251" ?>
<ValCurs Date="29.03.2017" name="Foreign Currency Market">
<Valute ID="R01010">
    <NumCode>036</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AUD</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Russian name1</Name>
    <Value>43,3058</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01020A">
    <NumCode>944</NumCode>
    <CharCode>AZN</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Russian name2</Name>
    <Value>32,8637</Value>
</Valute>
<Valute ID="R01035">
    <NumCode>826</NumCode>
    <CharCode>GBP</CharCode>
    <Nominal>1</Nominal>
    <Name>Russian name3</Name>
    <Value>71,6658</Value>
</Valute>
</ValCurs>
```

Here is my classes that I want to parse the response:

```
@Root(name = "Valute")
public class CbrValute {

    @Element(name = "Name", required = false)
    private String name;

    @Element(name = "Value", required = false)
    private String value;

    @Element(name = "ID", required = false)
    private String currencyId;

    @Element(name = "Nominal", required = false)
    private String nominal;

    @Element(name = "CharCode", required = false)
    private String charCode;

    @Element(name = "NumCode", required = false)
    private String numCode;
}
```

Response:

```
@Root(name = "ValCurs")
public class CbrResponse {

    @Attribute(name = "Date")
    private String date;

    @Attribute(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @ElementList(name = "Valute")
    private List<CbrValute> valuteList;
}
```

Everytime I run the app I get the crash that value is not satisfied:

```
Caused by: org.simpleframework.xml.core.ValueRequiredException: Unable to satisfy @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=ID, required=true, type=void) on field 'currencyId' private java.lang.String com.tryue.news18.repository.dto.CbrValute.currencyId for class com.tryue.news18.repository.dto.CbrValute at line 4
```

Or that value is already in use(when I made all fields as not required):

```
Element 'Valute' is already used with @org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList
```

So it seems like I've made something wrong in the beggining but I don't know how to trace it. Please help!

Comment: Maybe because `currencyId` is an attribute, not an element.

Comment: I've figured it out actually.  @ElementList(name = "Valute")
    private List<CbrValute> valuteList; should be inline!